# Definine one grid to hold all the items of a ListBox in stead of a grid for each using a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, datatemplate

I have a ListBox that is bound to a list of Persons. I want to show the items of the listbox in a grid. I can accomplish this with the code below, but the problem is that with this code each item has its own grid. I want one grid to contain all items so that each column in the grid is automatically scaled to the width of the longest string. I suppose I should bind data to a Grid in stead? How?

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition />
          <ColumnDefinition />
          <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Age}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=Gender}" />
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still accomplish this using the Grid inside of your DataTemplate.  You would just need to specify the [IsSharedSizeScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope.aspx) attached property on your ListBox and [SharedSizeGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup.aspx) property on the ColumnDefinitions you want to synchronize.

Alternatively you can define the ListBoxes' panel as a Grid, but I don't recommend that unless your Person objects have an ordering property which can be used easily to bind to Grid.Row.